# How to generate a function that, having the array above as input parameter, generates the following output?

Tags: javascript

given the following array:

```
[['team1','dep1','tkt1'], ['team2','dep1','tkt2'], ['team2','dep3','tkt75'], ['team2','dep1','tkt10']]
```

(where the internal array will always have team, dependency, tickets)

• Generate a function that, having the above array as input parameter, generates the following output:

```
[
    {
        "dependencies": [
            {
                "name": "dep1",
                "tickets": [
                    {
                        "name": "tkt1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name": "team1"
    },
    {
        "dependencies": [
            {
                "name": "dep1",
                "tickets": [
                    {
                        "name": "tkt2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tkt10"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "dep3",
                "tickets": [
                    {
                        "name": "tkt75"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name": "team2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please read through [this question about homework problems on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const input = [
  ["team1", "dep1", "tkt1"],
  ["team2", "dep1", "tkt2"],
  ["team2", "dep3", "tkt75"],
  ["team2", "dep1", "tkt10"],
];

const transform = (data) => {
    const teamDepMap = {};

    data.forEach(([team, dep, ticket]) => {
        if (!teamDepMap[team]) {
            teamDepMap[team] = {};
        }

        if (!teamDepMap[team][dep]) {
            teamDepMap[team][dep] = [{name: ticket}];
        } else {
            teamDepMap[team][dep].push({name: ticket});
        }
    });
    
    return Object.entries(teamDepMap).map(([team, dependencyMap]) => ({
        name: team,
        dependencies: Object.entries(dependencyMap).map(([dependency, tickets]) => ({
            name: dependency,
            tickets
        }))
    }))
}

console.log(transform(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const objectb = [];
function Convertarray(list){
    for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
             let c ={
                "dependencies": [
                    {
                        "name": list[i][1],
                        "tickets": [
                            {
                                "name": list[i][2]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": list[i][0]
            }
            objectb.push(c)
      }
      return objectb
}
let test=new Convertarray([['team1','dep1','tkt1'], ['team2','dep1','tkt2'], ['team2','dep3','tkt75'], ['team2','dep1','tkt10']])
console.log(test);
```

```js
const objectb = [];
function Convertarray(list){
    for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
             let c ={
                "dependencies": [
                    {
                        "name": list[i][1],
                        "tickets": [
                            {
                                "name": list[i][2]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": list[i][0]
            }
            objectb.push(c)
      }
      return objectb
}
let test=new Convertarray([['team1','dep1','tkt1'], ['team2','dep1','tkt2'], ['team2','dep3','tkt75'], ['team2','dep1','tkt10']])
console.log(test);
let myString = JSON.stringify(test);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myString;
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```